# C++ error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, cmake-gui

I used `Cmake` to define `folder paths`.

I have `Config.in.h` file and where `#cmakedefine` are declared as

```
#cmakedefine CAFFE_MODEL_PATH
#cmakedefine CAFFE_MODEL_PATH
#cmakedefine CAFFE_TRAIN_MODEL
#cmakedefine MEAN_FILE
#cmakedefine LABEL_FILE
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I did as

```
set(CAFFE_MODEL_PATH "" CACHE PATH "Path to a Caffe model")
set(CAFFE_TRAIN_MODEL "" CACHE PATH "Path to a trained model")
set(MEAN_FILE "" CACHE PATH "Path to the mean file all trained images")
set(LABEL_FILE "" CACHE PATH "Path to the mean file all trained images")
configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.h"
)
```

So that `Config.h` has #define for those `CAFFE_MODEL_PATH, CAFFE_TRAIN_MODEL, MEAN_FILE, LABEL_FILE`.

But when I use them in my main.cpp file

```
int main(void) {

    ::google::InitGoogleLogging("endtoenddetection");

    string model_file   = CAFFE_MODEL_PATH;
    string trained_file = CAFFE_TRAIN_MODEL;
    string mean_file    = MEAN_FILE;
    string label_file   = LABEL_FILE;
}
```

I have errors as

```
/home/Softwares/ReInspect/endtoendLstm/main.cpp:8:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
     string model_file   = CAFFE_MODEL_PATH;
                                           ^
/home/Softwares/ReInspect/endtoendLstm/main.cpp:9:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
     string trained_file = CAFFE_TRAIN_MODEL;
                                            ^
/home/Softwares/ReInspect/endtoendLstm/main.cpp:10:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
     string mean_file    = MEAN_FILE;
                                    ^
/home/Softwares/ReInspect/endtoendLstm/main.cpp:11:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token
     string label_file   = LABEL_FILE;
```

Comment: Do you have `#include "Config.h"` in `main.cpp`?

Comment: `So that Config.h has #define for those` - I guess it has `/* #undef VAR */` for all your macros (that is, **does not define them** at all). This is because content of corresponded variables in CMake is *empty*, which is evaluated by CMake as *false*. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/configure_file.html) for command `configure_file`. If you want to define macro with (possibly empty) string value, use `#define CAFFE_MODEL_PATH "@CAFFE_MODEL_PATH@"` in your file `Config.h.in`.

Comment: yes i include "Config.h" in main.cpp

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes you are right. Now it works. Can please answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `configure_file`, expression

```
#cmakedefine CAFFE_MODEL_PATH
```

is actually a **conditional macro definition**. That is, the macro is defined only when corresponded CMake variable is evaluated as *no-false* (according to [if(constant)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/if.html) rules).

In your case, CMake variables have *empty* values, which are evaluated as false. So configured file (`Config.h` in you case) **doesn't contain macros definitions**.

If you want to define macro with *string value*, use

```
#define CAFFE_MODEL_PATH "@CAFFE_MODEL_PATH@"
```

Such a way the macro will be properly defined even if corresponded variable is empty.

See also [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/configure_file.html) for `configure_file` command.